# Why does .limit() result empty array when using a query object as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, limit

I am setting up a mongoose query where I would like to find specific records, mentioned in a custom queryObject. This queryObject contains the key-value pairs, if existent. So, if the res.query does not contain the e.g. limit, it is not added to the queryObject.

For whatever reason, the queryObject.limit parameter results in an empty array. It does filter, when entering a variable that has a number assigned, though.

This does NOT work:

```
const showOneMovie = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {title, publishDate, genre, skip, sort} = req.query;
        const queryObject = {};
        if(title){
            queryObject.title = title;
        }
        if(publishDate){
            queryObject.publishDate = publishDate;
        }
        if(sort){
            sort === "Ascending" ? queryObject.sort = "-title" : queryObject.sort = "title";
        }
        queryObject.limit = 2;
        let data = await Movie.find(queryObject).limit(queryObject.limit);
        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

This works:

```
const showOneMovie = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {title, publishDate, genre, skip, sort} = req.query;
        const queryObject = {};
        if(title){
            queryObject.title = title;
        }
        if(publishDate){
            queryObject.publishDate = publishDate;
        }
        if(sort){
            sort === "Ascending" ? queryObject.sort = "-title" : queryObject.sort = "title";
        }
        const limit = 2;
        let data = await Movie.find(queryObject).limit(limit);
        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I know I could skip this issue, but I would really like to understand that behaviour.

Comment: if you add a property `limit` to `queryObject`, mongoose will try to filter records in your DB `WHERE limit=2` and I don't think you have a column named "limit" - so it returns an empty array

Comment: You are right! This was the problem and explains it. Thanks a lot @GrafiCode!
I cannot accept your answer as the solution, since it is a comment....

Comment: hopefully somebody else will be able to provide a proper answer to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for this answer should go to @GrafiCode but since only 1 wrong answer was posted we need a correct answer.

In your first example you have assigned a key name `limit` to the `queryObject` and have given it a value of 2:

```js
queryObject.limit = 2;
```

When you pass the `queryObject` to the find function here:

```js
let data = await Movie.find(queryObject).limit(queryObject.limit);
```

Mongoose expects your document to have properties of `title`, `publishDate` and `limit` because that's what you added to the `queryObject`, so that's what it thinks you're looking for (sort ignored for now).  Your `queryObject` might look something like this:

```js
{ 
   title: 'RoboCop',
   publishDate: 1987,
   limit: 10,
}
```

What mongoose then executes is this:

```js
let data = await Movie.find({ 
   title: 'RoboCop',
   publishDate: 1987,
   limit: 10,
}).limit(queryObject.limit);
```

Since your Schema does not contain a property of `limit`, mongoose doesn't find anything.

In your second example, you don't add `limit` to the `queryObject` and instead create a lexical scoped variabe `const limit = 2;` that is not part of the query until it's used to limit the results.